# Is it possible to redirect traffic to attacker's IP?

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, iptables, firewalld

Is it possible to redirect traffic to attacker's ip? 
For example if attacker tries brute force attack on port 22 it will redirect the traffic to its own ip.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is technically possible, but it may not be a good idea as the attacker may use techniques to show an IP address of an innocent person, hiding the real IP address.

Operating this redirection will depend on the service attacked, but note that redirecting traffic will cost ressource not only to you, but to all devices in the path of that redirection, redirecting the attack won't nullify the ressources consumption on your machine, and it can still be taken down.

A clean way would be to add a drop rule on your firewall after some failed attempts to login.

You can read various method to block ssh bruteforce [here](http://www.la-samhna.de/library/brutessh.html).
Proposed methods are iptables rules, sshd configuration hardening, using port knocking, use of keys instead of password.

You can automate the iptables rules management using Fail2Ban.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I understand that this is not a good practice to implement this mechanism. Just wanted to know the trick for my knowledge. If possible please teach me how to do that. :)

Thanks

Comment: `s/may not be a good idea/is a very bad idea/`. Actually, the IP address is genuine — you can't hide the IP address in a TCP connection, otherwise the other end would not receive the replies. The attacking machine probably doesn't belong to the attacker however — they're usually machines infected by malware.

Comment: The attacker doesn't need to receive your server response if the plans are denial of service and may send packer with false sender IP from unsecure networks that doesn't prevent forged paquets from leaving, but this point belongs to the security stackexchange.